# how can I iterate every index number in list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
list1 = [2,5,3]
for i in range(list1[]):
    print(i)
```

Desired Output:

```
0
1
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
```

I tried but I'm not able to iterate the indexes of list1.

Comment: Try to iterate list1 using a normal for loop and then use the range for each value in list1 and print that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to print the from `0` to `element-1`   for each element in the list.
use two loop, one to iterate on origanl list which give the element and second one to print element from 0 to element -1 respectively

```
list1 = [2,5,3]
for element in list1:
    for j in range(element):
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

So do it by step :

- for each value in the list

  - generate the values from 0 to the value (excluded)

---

```
list1 = [2,5,3]
for value in list1:
    for i in range(value):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just print `range(i)` values for every `i` in `list1`

```
list1 = [2, 5, 3]
for i in list1:
    print(*range(i), sep='\n')
```